# I have created a new thread and try to populate it .But the grid is not visible in browser

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ThreadStart st = new ThreadStart(Populate);
            Thread td = new Thread(st);
            td.Start();
        }
    }
    private void Populate()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.sales", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a new thread? Also make sure you use `using` keyword for declaring the Connection or Close the connection after it is processed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your new thread is still fetching data when the page is rendered.

So better do it like

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Populate();
        }
    }
    private void Populate()
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
         using(SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.sales", con))
         {
          con.Open();
          SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
          GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
          GridView1.DataBind();
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How long thread will take to fetch data.There are very few number of records in the sales table.

Comment: Why you need a separate thread in this event? Any specific reason? We create separate thread when the action to be performed is independent of the calling thread. But here, the Populate function need to finish after the  page rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Code:

```
private void Populate()
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    {
       using(var com = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.sales", con))
       {
         con.Open();
         com.CommandType= CommandType.Text;
         using(var rdr = com.ExecuteReader())
         {
           GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
           GridView1.DataBind();
         }
       }
     }
  }
```

If it doesn't works, try to removing new thread and use delegates to call the method Populate, if you want so.

[Here is a link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030720.asp) for using Asynchronous Methods. This is not the actual thing you required,but it will give you a good insight , how to use delegates to call a method asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

For asynchronous tasks, you can use [PageAsyncTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx) class.

In this case you must add Async="True" attribute.

```
<%@Page Async="True" ... %>
```